# How do I remove background-image in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a general rule which gives all DIVs a background image.
I have one div (with id='a') which I don't want it to have the background image.
What css rule do I have to give it?

Answer (score 374, accepted):

Try:

```
div#a {
    background-image:none
}
```

Comment: Just use `#a {}`. [Don't use element types in selectors unless necessary](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml#Type_selectors).

Comment: "Avoiding unnecessary ancestor selectors is useful for performance reasons."

Not really an issue when you are not Google.

Comment: W3C Recommendation on CSS 3 Selectors > Calculating a selector's specificity https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity

Answer (score 38):

```
div#a {
    background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 33):

```
div#a {
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

Although the "!important" might not be necessary, because "div#a" has a higher specificity than just "div".

Comment: The !important part is not necessary as the declaration with #a is more precise than a declaration of div and therefore this rule will be applied instead of the general div rule.

Comment: I found !important to be necessary in Chrome

Answer (score 19):

```
div#a {
  background-image: url('../images/spacer.png');
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

I use a transparent spacer image in addition to the rule to remove the background image because IE6 seems to ignore the `background-image: none` even though it is marked `!important`.

Comment: Who cares about IE6 these days.

Comment: -1 Your answer is incorrect. I started IE6, and the `background-image:none;` (with ot without `!important`) works flawlessly.

Comment: Actually, I care - one of my clients has an isolated network environment with some specific software that hasn't been updated. IE6 is what they have to use. Sad but true :(

Comment: Have an upvote to mitigate Rob W's downvote. It was quite rude of him to downvote just for backwards compatibility that isn't even a hack, regardless of if he could reproduce it or not

Answer (score 8):

Since in css3 one might set multiple background images setting "none" will only create a new layer and hide nothing.

http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#backgrounds

I have not found a solution yet...

Comment: I believe "background: none;" will override

Answer (score 3):

When `background-image: none !important;` have no effect.
You can use:

```
background-size: 0 !important;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #fff), color-stop(0.5, #fff));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top, #fff 0%, #fff 50%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #fff 0%, #fff 50%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 50%);
```

for older browsers.. if you have defined css in some framewokrk.css like select2.css in IE9 background-image: -webkit-gradient etc. and you want it via another .css rewrite with "background-image: none !important" not works. I used same color to color gradient like page background color.

Answer (score 1):

If your div rule is just `div {...}`, then `#a {...}` will be sufficient.  If it is more complicated, you need a "more specific" selector, as defined by the [CSS specification on specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).  (#a being more specific than div is just single aspect in the algorithm.)

Answer (score 1):

HTML :

```
<div id="a" class="mydiv"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div#a {
       background-image:none;
}
```

Another Way:

```
div:not(#a) {
     //all rules goes here 
     //add image here
     //div with id a not effected by these rules
   }
```

Multiple (not pseudo)

```
   div:not(#a):not(#b):not(#c) {
     //all rules goes here 
     //add image here
     //div with ids not effected with these rules
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work:

```
.clear-background{
background-image: none;
}
```

Might have problems on older browsers...

Answer (score 0):

Replace the rule you have with the following:

```
div:not(#a) { // add your bg image here //}
```