# Remove image in CSS

Tags: css, background

I have a background image defined in style.css for H1:

```
h1 {
    padding:10px 10px 5px 43px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:url('../images/marker2.png') 17px 5px no-repeat; 
    color:#7c7960; 
    font-size: 1.40em; 
    line-height:18px; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

But in certain H1 headers, i don't want this background image to appear? How to make exception in below code so that background image doesnt show?

```
<h1 itemprop="name" ><?php echo $products_name; ?></h1>
```

Comment: You should bother to do a search before posting a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461077/how-do-i-remove-background-image-in-css

Answer (score 1):

Write like this:

```
h1[itemprop="name"]{
 background-image:none;
}
```

For example check this http://jsfiddle.net/X2Aef/

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
<h1 itemprop="name" style="background-image: none;" ><?php echo $products_name; ?></h1>
```

Comment: Inline CSS isn't best practice and should never be considered as an good answer.

Comment: @Schwierig I know but I think it is good suitable for his requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<h1 itemprop="name" style="background:none;"><?php echo $products_name; ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add class like `h1.noBg{background:none}` and pass this to the  elements where background is not required.other option is use inline style elements like

```
<h1 itemprop="name" style="background:none;">
```

But this is not a good practice. Using class to override a rule is better.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
<h1 itemprop="name" style="background:none !important;"><?php echo $products_name; ?></h1>
```